# Powershell: How can I get the UNC path from an OpenFileDialog without the leaf?

Tags: powershell, path, openfiledialog, unc

I'm still a beginner in Powershell...
I'm using the OpenFileDialog to give the user the possibility to choose a file on the network.

Add some .net Assembly for OpenFileDialog and MessageBox

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
```

This is the OpenFileDialog-Definition

```
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
```

With this the OpenFileDialog will be opened and shown to the user for choosing a file

```
$null = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
```

This is the UNC-filename with extension included that the user has chosen in OpenFileDialog

```
$full_filename = $FileBrowser.FileName
```

This is only the filename with extension (leaf) that the user has chosen in OpenFileDialog

```
$filename = $FileBrowser.SafeFileName
```

This converts the array-elements into strings

```
$full_filename_string = [string]$full_filename
$filename_string = [string]$filename
```

So far, so good.
What I would need additionally is the UNC-path ONLY from the subdirectory, in which the user has chosen a file (UNC-path without the leaf).

How could this be accomplished?

Comment: The description of what you need is a bit confusing - can you show an example of `$full_filename_string` and what your desired result would look like?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Example of $full_filename_string:
\\contoso.com\data\sub11\sub12\sub13\leaf.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Split-Path` cmdlet:

```
PS ~> '\\hostname\share\path\to\directory\with_file.exe' |Split-Path -Parent
\\host\share\path\to\directory
```

Beware that the `Split-Path` will convert `\` to `/` on linux file systems, to avoid that you'd have to manually split the string on the last occurrence of `\`:

```
PS ~> $path,$name = '\\hostname\share\path\to\directory\with_file.exe' -split '\\(?=[^\\]*$)'
PS ~> $path
\\hostname\share\path\to\directory
PS ~> $name
with_file.exe
```